# What difference bettween these two type of tensor?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection

I am confused about the #2 type of tensor, how can I get its list type? For example, I can get the list type of predictions by predictions.tolist(), what about #2?

```
print(predictions) #return #1
print(bboxes) #return #2
>>>tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], device='cuda:0') #1
>>>Boxes(tensor([[ 56.6679, 568.2880, 297.5019, 697.3653],             #2
        [315.3174, 556.3110, 555.8267, 720.8016],
        ...
        [ 56.5737, 134.1078, 497.3640, 165.2118]], device='cuda:0'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are running an object detection model (e.g., YoLo, RCNN, etc.).
These models predict, for each detected box, its class (`predictions` in your case), and the bounding box this object occupies in the image (`bboxes` in your case).

The `bboxes` prediction uses a project-specific class `Boxes`. You should refer to the specific code you are running to see how this class is defined and how to iterate it.

Please note that in many object-detection frameworks, some of the returned `bboxes` are "background": that is they do not contain an actual object. Again, this is implementation dependant and you should know how the model you are using behaves.